# How to deal with lots of brackets in a formula?

Tags: linux, vim, worksheet-function, latex, maple

Say, I have a formula like this (in LaTeX or Maple or other text system):

```
Result: ((6*(k2+k3))*A123*k2*k3*(A12*A13*k2^2-2*A12*A13*k2*k3+A12*A13*k3^2-A123*k2^2-2*A123*k2*k3-A123*k3^2)*(exp(-k3*(k3^2*t-x)))^2+6*A12*(-k3+k2)*k2*k3*(A12*A13*k2^2-2*A12*A13*k2*k3+A12*A13*k3^2-A123*k2^2-2*A123*k2*k3-A123*k3^2)*exp(-k3*(k3^2*t-x)))*(exp(-k2*(k2^2*t-x)))^2+(-(6*(-k3+k2))*A13*k2*k3*(A12*A13*k2^2-2*A12*A13*k2*k3+A12*A13*k3^2-A123*k2^2-2*A123*k2*k3-A123*k3^2)*(exp(-k3*(k3^2*t-x)))^2-(6*(k2+k3))*k2*k3*(A12*A13*k2^2-2*A12*A13*k2*k3+A12*A13*k3^2-A123*k2^2-2*A123*k2*k3-A123*k3^2)*exp(-k3*(k3^2*t-x)))*exp(-k2*(k2^2*t-x))
```

> Note: the above formula is only one part of the result of a maple calculation, I just can't break them up because there are so many many terms.

Apparently, It's very hard to read. **What I want to do is to fold the matched brackets level by level.** If all the brackets are folded, I can find out clearly how many terms there are. Then I can analyze from the top level to the details of every term. But I just don't know how to realize that. Maybe there are some existed software which can visualize this kind of complex formula. Any idea?

P.S. I use Linux system. The open source alternatives are better.

Comment: well, an idea, on paper at least. is you can write |____| below pairs of brackets. That gives great clarity, though I don't know software if any, does that.. Also, some development IDEs might color code pairs but that probably wouldn't give the clarity you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Their is a vim script called [foldcol.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1161) but I can't say more.

Personnaly I will do :

```
"put every calculs on one line
:%s/(/\r(\r/g
:%s/)/\r)\r/g

"delete all empty lines
:g/^$/d
"set fold as () to collapse them with "za"
:set foldmethod=marker foldmarker=(,)

"indent all text:
gg=G
```

It should look like :

```
Result: (
         (
          6*(
            k2+k3
            )
         )
         *A123*k2*k3*(
           A12*A13*k2^2-2*A12*A13*k2*k3+A12*A13*k3^2-A123*k2^2
           )
         *(
.
.
.
```

After working on it, remove indent : go to first line and then press :

```
 gg<G............ "need to press dot to repeat
 500gJ "to put all on one line
```

Answer (score 1):

Folding only applies to multiple lines. For a single line, the best you can do is use the recent *conceal* feature; unfortunately, it requires more scripting to set up, may interfere with existing syntax highlighting, and you don't have the convenient "show (more / less) folds" mappings at hand.

You're probably aware of the *matchparen* plugin that ships with Vim. There are also plugins like [rainbow_parentheses.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3772) that improve on that.